# Combinatorics: Envelopes and cells

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $X$ labeled (different/unique) envelopes and $X$ empty (not labeled) envelopes.
How many ways are there, to arrange those envelopes to:

1. $Y$ numbered cells, such that each cell contains exactly $1$ envelop. $(Y\ge X)$.
2. $2X$ numbered cells, such that at most, one empty envelop for each cell.
3. $X-10$ numbered cells, such that each cell contains at least one empty envelop.

**My answers:**

1. First, we choose $k$ labeled envelops. there are $k!$ permutations for them. Then, we choose the $(y-k)$ empty envelopes. Hence, 
   $$\sum\limits_{k = y - x}^x {\left( {\matrix{
      x  \cr 
      k  \cr 
    } } \right)} k!(y - k)$$
2. We choose $k$ empty envelopes, and for the labeled one there are no limitations. Hence,
   $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^x {\left( {\matrix{
      {2x}  \cr 
      k  \cr 
    } } \right)}  \cdot \left( {\matrix{
      {2x}  \cr 
      x  \cr 
    } } \right)$$
3. First, we place a-priory $X-10$ empty envelopes. So, $10$ empty envelopes left,
   $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{10} {\left( {\matrix{
      {x - 10}  \cr 
      k  \cr 
    } } \right)} $$

How to complete $3$? Are $1$, and $2$ correct?
Thanks.